# Find type of currently read Word object during parsing with python-openxml module python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I want to extract text and tables from a file in docx format. In order to perform this, I use [python-docx](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx) Python 3 library; it works pretty well, the text and tables are correctly extracted.

However, my use-case requires me to parse text and tables **in the same order** they appear within the document, i.e. during the processing of the page, I need to know the type of the currently read object (objects is understood in the Word-sense, i.e. a paragraph, a table, etc.) to keep this document order.

Perhaps my explanations seem confusing, so I let you have a look at the code I wrote, directly inspired by [this](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#paragraph-objects) part of the documentation :

```
def readLines(self):
    # Load DOCX document parser.
    docxDocument = docx.Document(self._fileHandle)

    # Add each line of paragraph in a string.
    pagesLines = []
    for paragraph in docxDocument.paragraphs:
        for line in paragraph.text.split('\n'):
            pagesLines.append(tuple([line, 0]))

    # Add each line from tables.
    for table in docxDocument.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                    for line in paragraph.text.split('\n'):
                        pagesLines.append(tuple([line, 0]))

    # Return the list of strings.
    return pagesLines
```

*(Please do not consider the appended tuple to the `pagesLines` list since the they are only used to store a metadata used by my parser, but that the docx document is unable to provide : the tuple is added only to keep compatibility with parser and removed in the calling function).*

As you can see, the problem is I have to read **first** all text contained in *paragraphs* objects **then** all text contained within the *tables* objects.

Finally, my question is : does a method exist to parse docx at the Word object level, determining during parsing the type of the object (paragraph, table, etc.) to be able to call the right text retrieving method ?

In other words, is it possible to write something which loops on the document, and allows to know the type of the current object in order to be able to correctly parse this part of the document ?

Help will be greatly appreciated !

Thank you !

Comment: This is a well-known issue, see this thread on GitHub issues list: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/40

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly the response I expected ! :)